# How do I search and get text off a raw webpage? vc++?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-c++

This is the [link](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=yVyxkWFD) I have that contains a big list of data which has the format:

" X = MapNumber : Y = MapName "

example

" 10000: Mushroom Park ".

In vc++ .net I would want to code a function that connects to that link, searches for a number within the data (let's say 10000) and then gets the name beside the number (which would be Mushroom Park) and then put's the name into a string.

The code below is what I have already and would work if all the data was inside a .txt file but I would like to convert this code into connecting to the link above and finally making it more efficient.

Thanks.

```
String^ GrabMapNameById(String^ CurrentStr)//Current Map String{
if(CurrentMapIDRead.ToString() != CurrentMapID.ToString()) //If map has chnaged
{
       try //Try streaming text
       {
          String^ Maps = "Strife.Maps";//map File Name
          StreamReader^ MapDin = File::OpenText("Strife.Maps");//Stream Declar

          String^ str;
          string s;
          int count = 0;
          while ((str = MapDin->ReadLine()) != nullptr) //Loop for every line
          {
             if(str->Contains(CurrentMapID.ToString())) //Untill Map id found
             {
                CurrentMapIDRead = CurrentMapID; //Set Current Map Name
                CurrentStr = str->Replace(CurrentMapIDRead.ToString() , "" );//Replace map id with null characters
                CurrentStr = CurrentStr->Replace(" =" , "" ); //Take out = characters
                break;// kill while
             }
          }
       }

           catch (Exception^ e)
           {
           }
}return CurrentStr;}
```

Comment: If possible, look up [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). Windows binaries are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked with vc++ before, but I believe you're looking for the WebRequest class to get the data. Microsoft has a [tutorial](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/815657) on making such a request. It uses a stream reader so the code inside the try block would look something like this:

```
String *sURL = S"http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=yVyxkWFD";
WebRequest *wrGETURL;
wrGETURL = WebRequest::Create(sURL);
WebProxy *myProxy = new WebProxy(S"myproxy", 80);
myProxy->BypassProxyOnLocal = true;

wrGETURL->Proxy = WebProxy::GetDefaultProxy();

Stream *objStream = wrGETURL->GetResponse()->GetResponseStream();

StreamReader *MapDin = new StreamReader(objStream);

String^ str;
string s;
int count = 0;
while ((str = MapDin->ReadLine()) != nullptr) //Loop for every line
{
     if(str->Contains(CurrentMapID.ToString())) //Untill Map id found
     {
         CurrentMapIDRead = CurrentMapID; //Set Current Map Name
         CurrentStr = str->Replace(CurrentMapIDRead.ToString() , "" );//Replace map id with null characters
         CurrentStr = CurrentStr->Replace(" =" , "" ); //Take out = characters
         break;// kill while
     }
}
```